# How to collect contact information from websites?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy, google-crawlers, crawler4j

Does anyone know a web crawler tool for collecting contact details from a website? Say I have a www.website/contact.. I want to pull out the address, phone number, etc.. There are 2 tools I've been looking at: cralwer4j opensource jar for java and Scrapy opensource in Python. But I am finding it a bit hard to use for my scenario.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might google for "[simple web crawler](https://www.google.lv/search?q=simple%20web%20crawler&oq=simple%20web%20crawler&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.303j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)" to find a solution that fits you best. In the net there are plenty "pure python" based web crawlers. Based on sceleton code you add db wrap up. I think the most problem would be db setting and saving data in it.

> What if there are 1000000s of websites to crawl.. Is there a way to crawl all websites in my are?

No problem for scripting. Just put millions addresses in a file (or files), open it for reading in python or other script. Then get link by link from it and crawl/scrape to your pleasure. Result you might also want to save in file (csv, json).

I'd also recommend you a ready [simple python crawler](http://webscraping.pro/simple-email-crawler-python/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to save the data in a csv file.. With the examples I've seen the problem would be that I would need to point the crawler to the website/domain.. What if there are 1000000s of websites to crawl.. Is there a way to crawl all websites in my are?